# set dynamic tableview height constraint in storyboard swift

Tags: swift

i am using `tableview` and `autolayout`. I want to display array count based increase the `tableview` height in storyboard. how to do this?

I am using below code but not working

```
@property(strong,nonatomic)iboutlet nslayoutconstraint *dynamicheight;

self.dynamicheight.constant=[self.array count]*44
```

kindly help me anyone for this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jadT7.png
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/dP3tZ.png

Comment: Please follow this link, it will be useful : https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells

Comment: your question and an accepted answer are mismatching. Read the question title you have asked, and look at the answer you have accepted, @Prisy

Comment: but its working for tableview dynamic height in swift

Comment: thats not dynamic height. It's just hiding the rows based on number of cells. If you want to check dynamic tableView height, set the background color red or something to tableview and then check the output.

Comment: please check my question i will ask array count based increase the tableview height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-

if you are using tableView cell add below code within `cellForRowAt` method

```
  cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
  cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
```

And also set these properties of UITableView within `viewDidLoad`

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 120 //Your estimated height
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Hope it will work :)

Check below complete code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var guestTView: UITableView!

var guests: [String]?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.guests = ["hi this is john and i am a ios developer gjjgjgjgjg hzsg bnfddf dfbdnvfvd bdhgfjgjfgn ngfjggffgfhgh hdfghfggsgg","hi this is john and i am a ios developer gjjgjgjgjg hzsg bnfddf dfbdnvfvd bdhgfjgjfgn ngfjggffgfhgh hdfghfggsg","hi this is john and i am a ios developer gjjgjgjgjg hzsg bnfddf dfbdnvfvd bdhgfjgjfgn ngfjggffgfhgh hdfghfggsg","hi this is john and i am a ios developer gjjgjgjgjg hzsg bnfddf dfbdnvfvd bdhgfjgjfgn ngfjggffgfhgh hdfghfggsg","hi this is john and i am a ios developer gjjgjgjgjg hzsg bnfddf dfbdnvfvd bdhgfjgjfgn ngfjggffgfhgh hdfghfggsg","hi this is john and i am a ios developer gjjgjgjgjg hzsg bnfddf dfbdnvfvd bdhgfjgjfgn ngfjggffgfhgh hdfghfggsg","hi this is john and i am a ios developer gjjgjgjgjg hzsg bnfddf dfbdnvfvd bdhgfjgjfgn ngfjggffgfhgh hdfghfggsg"]

    self.guestTView.estimatedRowHeight = 70.0
    self.guestTView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.guestTView.tableFooterView = UIView()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }

}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return (guests?.count)!
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    cell.textLabel?.text = guests?[indexPath.row]

    return cell

 }

}
```

Comment: cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
 it shows error

Comment: what is that error please show me.

Comment: i need dynamic tableview height based on array content. but not set

Comment: In your storyboard only add top, bottom, trailing and leading constraint for UITablView.

Comment: thanks its working fine

Comment: great :) All the best...

Comment: can you please tell me its working for uitableviewcell height based on content

Comment: Yes, It is calculating height of cell  based on its content..

Comment: its working thanks

Answer (score 0):

use following

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView! //connect the table view

//do following in viewDidLoad method
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100 //Your estimated height
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Comment: its not working @rock

Comment: show some more code and your storyboard. please

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jadT7.png

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dP3tZ.png

Comment: Have you setup correct constraints in tableViewCell?

Comment: im not using custom cell.  i am using tableview cell. i added constraints for tableview not the tableviewcell

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `tableView` `height` to be dynamic, follow these steps:

1) Apply only `leading`, `trailing`, `top` and `Height` constrains to tableview.

2) Delete the `bottom` constraint that you have applied.

3) take an outlet of that `height` constraint as:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

4) in `viewWillAppear()` change the `dynamicHeight` constraint as:

```
let rowCount = self.array.count
self.dynamicHeight.constant = CGFloat(rowCount) * 44
view.updateConstraints()
self.yourTableView.reloadData()
```

And after this I don't see any point in implementing `UITableViewAutomaticDimention` and `estimatedRowHeight`

It's written in **Swift** Change it to objective C

Comment: i am already used this. but not working

Comment: I also don't know what prissy did and what not. Bcz I gave the correct answer though prissy preferred other user even she gave my copied answer. and now my answer got deleted bcz of prssy.

Comment: i am not delete your question i checked all the answers and which one is comes result i put the vote. thanks anyway for all your answers for my question:)