# How to calculate or auto fit height of UiTableView in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My TableView contents 3 controller.

1) WebView 1

2) ImageView

3) Webview 2

I am doing dynamically set the frame size of all 3 controller. So row height should be changed according of content sizes.

```
                    self.secondWebViewLable.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                                                       y: Int(self.firstImage.frame.origin.y + self.firstImage.frame.height),
                                                       width: Int(screenSize.width),
                                                       height: Int(self.secondWebViewLable.frame.height) )
self.firstImage.frame  = CGRect(x: 0,
                                                        y: Int(self.firstWebViewLable.frame.origin.y + self.firstWebViewLable.frame.height),
                                                        width: Int(screenSize.width),
                                                        height: Int(scaledHeight) )
```

you can see that controllers height is changing based on data. I am trying to set the height of cell also. below is my code. but i fixed the height. kindly help me.

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

      return screenSize.height
    }
```

Comment: try using stackviews

Comment: Try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42081813/set-dynamic-tableview-height-constraint-in-storyboard-swift/42082482#42082482

Answer (score 1):

**With Autolayout**

Set the estimated row height in **viewDidLoad()** and Return **UITableViewAutomaticDimension** from **heightForRowAt indexPath** method.

Refer this tutorial for more detailed explanation: [self-sizing-table-view-cells](https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells)

**Without Autolayout**

Without Autolayout you have to calculate height for each cell by adding the heights of all the UI components in the cell and margins and return that calculated height in UITableView datasource method **tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:**

Comment: Thanks but i don't want to use AutoLayout. can we resolve it without autolayout?